# How do I use sqlite3_key()?

Tags: sqlite, sqlcipher

I built `sqlcipher` with `mingw`.
I wanted to access sqlite(DB) encrypted in mfc(C++).
So, `sqlite3_open ()` was applied correctly. but, `sqlite3_open()` did not return a result, so I wanted to use `sqlite3_key()`.
When using `sqlite3_key()`, `sqlite3_key()` is not defined.
How do I use `sqlite3_key()`? Or how do I activate `sqlite3_key()` function?

Answer (score 0):

[`sqlite3_open(...)`](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html) will return a [result code](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_abort.html). If you are not receiving `SQLITE_OK` as a result, you may wish to investigate the error code with [`sqlite3_errcode(...)`](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/errcode.html) Alternatively, you might review your build process to make sure everything is compiling properly.